# Identification of Secondary metabolites gene clusters in fungi

Tags: dna-sequencing, pcr, mycology

I am trying to identify secondary metabolites gene clusters specifically PKS from endophytes through PCR then sanger sequencing. Are there set of specific primers available or do I have to design my own?

Comment: What fungal species is it ? Are there primers in the literature designed by people who study the same secondary metabolites as you ?
What aspect of the gene clusters do you want to study ?